# Populate combobox with a class - data from a sql query

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010, combobox, ado.net

Iam frustrated to accomplish a simply population of a combobox, below I have added one new item to the combobox everything seems to be fine.

Question 1 : But how could I get there the information's from the sql query, without having to add it all manually. [ I suppose by simply adding Items.Add line to the while loop ], but here is another thing - The start data is a database record previewer, So it is Simple Name Simple Surname [/] with a dropdown menu with all customers,

[image]

Question 2. The data I get from the mysql result is id,name,surname how to point it as the current displayed name/surname and for later purposes - like a update get the selected id of another customer from the dropdown? I don't need the insert command or code just need the information how can I get the id from a selection. If something is unclear don't hesitate to ask.

```
'Select the first item ( the selection would be a ID of the customer which isn't the index at all)
ComboBoxEdit.SelectedIndex = 0
```

Form

```
Dim properties As DevExpress.XtraEditors.Repository.RepositoryItemComboBox = _
            ComboBoxEdit.Properties
properties.Items.Add(New Customers(1, "Ta", "t").ToString)
'Select the first item ( the selection would be a ID of the customer which isn't the index at all)
ComboBoxEdit.SelectedIndex = 0
```

Getting customers into Class Customers ( I guess its that way I need to do it )

```
Public Function init_customers()
        ' Create a list of strings.
        Dim sql As String
        Dim myReader As MySqlDataReader

        con.Open()
        sql = "select * from customers"
        'bind the connection and query
        With cmd
            .Connection = con
            .CommandText = sql
        End With
        myReader = cmd.ExecuteReader()
        While myReader.Read()
            list.Add(New Customers(myReader.GetInt64(0), myReader.GetString(1), myReader.GetString(2)))
        End While
        con.Close()
        'Return list
    End Function
```

The class customers

```
Public Class Customers

    Public Sub New(ByVal id As Integer, ByVal name As String, ByVal surname As String)
        Me.ID = id
        Me.Imie = name
        Me.Nazwisko = surname

    End Sub
#Region "Get/Set"
    Public Property ID() As Integer
        Get
            Return Me._id
        End Get
        Set(ByVal value As Integer)
            Me._id = value
        End Set
    End Property
    Public Property Imie() As String
        Get
            Return Me._imie
        End Get
        Set(ByVal value As String)
            Me._imie = value
        End Set
    End Property
    Public Property Nazwisko() As String
        Get
            Return Me._nazwisko
        End Get
        Set(ByVal value As String)
            Me._nazwisko = value
        End Set
    End Property
    Public ReadOnly Property Surname() As Decimal
        Get
            Return Me._nazwisko
        End Get
    End Property
    Public Overrides Function ToString() As String
        Return _imie + " " + _nazwisko
    End Function
#End Region
    Private _id As Integer
    Private _imie As String
    Private _nazwisko As String

End Class
```

=========== Edit 2 =====================

Ok my dropdown is populated

[image]

As I said this is a record preview form so how can I get now the default selection of the combobox.
The thing is I pass there a string

```
Form1.GridView1.GetRowCellValue(Form1.GridView1.FocusedRowHandle, "Wystawione_na").ToString()
```

This code returns me SimpleName SimpleSurname - as a one string
Same method is applied to combobox display.

How can I get now the Id of the item, it has to somehow compared and returning a id so it could be set cmbx.SelectedIndex = 0 as the id of customer selection

Comment: To populate *from a class*, do what I showed you before - add them to a list and use the list as a bindingsource.  This is much less efficient than Keith's answer because you basically have to bring all the data to the PC in order to build a bunch of objects for the list.

Comment: your question is becoming a [chameleon question](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/275138/1070452) with little relation to the original.  If you find the data binding to work, you should mark Keiths answer and ask your new question.  That said passing a name is a really bad idea - you have no guarantee there is one "Bob Smith" in the DB

Comment: @Plutonix there always be the name so thats not the probblem

Comment: I think you missed the point.  You/your code has no guarantee that there will be one and *only one* Customer with that name.  It is the whole reason DBs assign unique IDs to records.  use it.

Comment: @Plutonix Managed to get the id's not the names, so as I assumed there is no way to get the id from the dataadapter, because combobox's index is 0 where the first customer id is 199..

Comment: you should accept this answer and ask a new question. a data adapter would not factor into how I would do it.

Comment: @Plutonix there is no need to making a new post, its still the same thing.

Comment: Edit 2: `Ok my dropdown is populated...`

Comment: @Plutonix what ever. The ids arent equal to the index

Comment: They dont need to be!  ValueMember will give you the ID of the item selected.  When the control is bound, you can get at the actual data (vs teh index of a copy of the data in something else).

Comment: @Plutonix well try to write it all in the bounty topic with examples how to get the ids etc so I can accept. This one is closed

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I take a simpler route, not sure if it's the most efficient though:

```
Dim Conn As New SqlConnection
Conn.ConnectionString = sYourConnectionString
Conn.Open()

Dim da As New SqlDataAdapter("select * from customers", Conn)
Dim ds As New DataSet
da.Fill(ds, sSql)

cmbxCustomers.DataSource = ds.Tables(0)
cmbxCustomers.ValueMember = "ID" 'or whatever column you want
```

Of course, I normally use a wrapper class to do almost all of the above code, but the last two lines apply to part of your question.

As far as retrieving that data later based on the ID selected: well you can simply use a DataSet (or DataTable, my preference) class member variable so the data is stored the from the initial load and iterate through the table looking for the row that matches the ID you're wanting information from.

Comment: @kavvson Note that when binding UI controls to a DB Datasource, you no longer need the Customer Class (for this).  You can create something like a `FullName` field in SQL and use that as the `DisplayMember` as in: `SELECT ID, FirstName & ' ' & LastName As FullName FROM ..."`

Comment: @Plutonix seems to be working but  cmbx.SelectedIndex = 0, rhis part needs a help too. Im passing my data to the checkbox which would be selected default with this code Form1.GridView1.GetRowCellValue(Form1.GridView1.FocusedRowHandle, "Wystawione_na").ToString()  its a string which is a name and surname in a string, my database returns also a string (fname+surname). I would need something like string comparison so fname+sname in checkbox = fname + sname in input ( always true ) but I need to have the id there to get the default selection

Comment: @Kavvson if it is bound, you would not use `SelectedIndex` - use `SelectedValue` to get the ID of the selected customer; likewise you probably want to respond to the `ValueMemberChanged` event

Comment: @Plutonix added a edit in question might be little more clarified. Selected value ok, maybe first I need to get the value of the getrowcellvalue inside the combobox